# How to freeze the browser while doing test on Moodle?

Tags: moodle, freeze

I have made a test on Moodle and my requirement is to freeze the browser, so that the student while giving the test, is not able to open any other window. Also I don't want to use Safe Exam Browser(SEB) until there is no other solution to it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use SEB? It's working well in our exams. Did you have some specific problems with it?

Comment: Reason being SEB requires intallation on every system, which makes it a cumbersome job to first install and prepare the systems before conducting the test.

Comment: You either need a lockdown browser like Respondus Lockdown Browser (commercial) or Safe Exam Browser (free). Or you use a limited operating system image (usually based on Linux) just allowing a browser to run in a kiosk mode which you boot on your machines (Netboot or from USB sticks). Chromebooks seem to have a built-in kiosk mode, also managed iOS devices can easily be locked into a single app mode (use a browser app with a kiosk mode like iCab).

You cannot simply lock a browser and even if you achieve something similar they could easily switch to another browser.